# DHCP frames (DISCOVER/REQUEST frames) have AutoIp address as source IPv4 address in Ipv4 header

Tags: dhcp

In my TcpIp stack, I want to trigger AutoIp/LinkLocal and DHCP addresss assignemtn parellelly. But the response from the DHCP server is too slow. By the time I get a reponse from DHCP server the AutoIp address assignment is over and assigned to my interface (NIC). After this the DHCP frames (DISCOVER/REQUEST frames) have AutoIp address as source IPv4 address in Ipv4 header.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

While this behaviour is unusual, RFC2131 allows it.  The client should not set the broadcast flag in this case.